# How to group by json using reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, reduce

Please take a look at my current json. I want to recursively group by this one.

```
[{ "mode": "AR", "fname": "ta", "lname": "da", "w_lng": 
             "1.23", "w_lat": "2.23","other":"a"},
           { "mode": "AR", "fname": "ta", "lname": "Dash", "w_lng": 
             "1.23", "w_lat": "2.23","other":"b" },
           { "mode": "AR1", "fname": "ka", "lname": "ja", "w_lng": 
             "3.23", "w_lat": "4.23","other":"c" },
           { "mode": "AR", "fname": "Kiran", "lname": "Dash", "w_lng": 
             "5.23", "w_lat": "6.23","other":"d" },
           { "mode": "AR", "fname": "Milan", "lname": "Dash", "w_lng": 
             "7.23", "w_lat": "8.23","other":"e" },
           { "mode": "AR1", "fname": "ka", "lname": "ja", "w_lng": 
             "8.23", "w_lat": "9.23","other":"f" }]
```

What I am am looking for:

```
  {
  "mode": "AR",
  "results": [
    {
    "fname": "ta",
    "lname": "da",
    "w_level": [
                { "w_lng": "1.23",
                  "w_lat": "2.23"
                  "other":[{"other":"a","other":"b"}]
                },
                {"w_lng": "3.xx",
                 "w_lat": "4.xx"
                 "....":[........]
                }
              ]  
   }
   {
    "fname": "ka",
    "lame": "ja",
    "w_level": [
        {
            "w_lng": "6.xx",
            "w_lat": "5.xx"
            .....................
                }
              ]  
   }
 ]
},
{
  "mode": "AR1",
  "results": [
    {
    "fname": "ka",
    "lname": "ja",
    "w_level": [
                { "w_lng": "6.xx",
                  "w_lat": "5.xx"
                  "....":[........]
                }
              ]  
   }

 ]
}
```

What I have tried:

```
Object.values(inArr.reduce((item, currItem) => {

var { mode, fname, lname } = currItem;

if (!item[mode]) item[mode] = { mode, results: [] }; 

let w_level = {};
for (let key of Object.keys(currItem)) {
  if (key !== "fname" && key !== 'lname' && key !== 'mode') {
    w_level[key] = currItem[key];
  }
}

item[mode].results.push({fname: fname, lname: lname, w_level: [w_level]});
return item;
}, {}))
```

But the problem is fname and lname again even it is same. I want to group by recursively. First it will group by mode. Then it will group by fname+lname under this mode. if anything same it will be added like tree.

Comment: The proposed result is impossible; you can't have duplicate keys in an object. Can you update it to clarify your intent?

Comment: This json comes when I took data from table by join. Just think Like 
Groupby country, 
then group by city, 
then group by ward etc...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm being clear enough. In your result, you want an object like this: `{"fname": "ka", "fname": "ja"}`. Such an object is impossible--try it.

Comment: @ggorlen That's probably just a typo, I believe OP meant `lname`. But good catch anyway.

Comment: No doubt, but that along with the `...` elipses in the output make it a lot less clear than it could be. I think OP would do themselves a service by showing the exact correct output to avoid any confusion or ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my final solution. The user can specify the key for grouping.

```js
const reduceArrayByKeys = (inArr, keys, restKey) => {
    const reduced = inArr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
        const copied = { ...cur }
        keys.forEach(key => delete copied[key])
        const existing = prev.find(item => keys.every(key => item[key] === cur[key]))
        if (existing) {
            existing[restKey].push(copied)
        } else {
            const newItem = {}
            keys.forEach(key => newItem[key] = cur[key])
            newItem[restKey] = [copied]
            prev.push(newItem)
        }
        return prev
    }, [])

    return reduced
}
```

We can specify the keys by which we are going to group the array. We can use this reduceArrayByKeys function to group the array as we want. Below is the example code

```js
const reduced = reduceArrayByKeys(inArr, ['mode'], 'results')
reduced.forEach(item => {
    const results = item.results
    item.results = reduceArrayByKeys(results, ['fname', 'lname'], 'w_level')

    item.results.forEach(child => {
        child.w_level = reduceArrayByKeys(child.w_level, ['w_lng', 'w_lat'], 'other')
    })
})
```

You can call reduceArrayByKeys function for w_level as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am checking right now. I hope it will work.

Comment: Suppose I want to reduce in w_level now.
reduced.forEach(item => {
    const w_level= item.results.w_level;
    item.results.w_level= reduceArrayByKeys(w_level, ['w_lng', 'w_lat'], 'other')
})

but it does not work. Can you please check ?

Comment: item.results is an array. you should call forEach once again for item.results. so item.results.forEach(child => {child.w_level = reduceArrayByKeys(child.w_level, ...)})

Comment: Changed my data. Please take a look at

Comment: I changed the post. Your data looks wrong. { "mode": "AR", "fname": "ta", "da": "Dash", "w_lng": "1.23", "w_lat": "2.23","other":"b" }. "da": "Dash" should be "lname": "da"?